# How to specify the current certificate for PHP CURL calls on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, curl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I downloaded the certificate from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and specified the full path to the file for CURLOPT_CAINFO

I keep getting the error - Curl error: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)

I am on Mac OS Sierra, 10.12 and PHP 7.0.11

Where do I get a valid certificate to make a SSL API call?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: show your code ...

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Added code

Comment: ok, quite similar to my setup (which works). The only difference i note is that i provide a fully qualified file path for the CAINFO filename.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - sorry, forgot to mention, I did try with the full path, didn't work either. I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, it is something to do with mac os settings. The exact same code works on ubuntu

Comment: could you add to your question the output of `which curl`, `brew list`, and `curl --version`